# Error Could not connect to server; are you sure it's running? In appium

Tags: appium

I am getting this error. How to solve this.

Comment: provide appium server logs and code you are running. You asking question without giving any relevant input.

Comment: It got solved.I have installed new version of appium and while entering I didn't mention udid along with other capabilities. After installing I have mentioned.Now, It is working fine.

Comment: Is there any way to validate xpath like firepath in firefox for webapplication in appium? Can you  assist me ,is there any other tool to do this?

Answer (score 18):

Just tick the below checkbox "Allow Unauthorized Certificates" for appium versions 1.6.*[image]

and make sure you are under "Automatic Server" tab

[image]

Comment: Edited the above answer

Answer (score 5):

Go to automatic server option and start session . and give the right path of apk file. it is work for me
(appium server 1.7)

Comment: He's right even i faced the same issue today and found this answer which worked for me. By default i was on custom server option, i had to click on automatic server option and then i was able to start the session. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After searching and applying lots of solutions finally i did following settings for Successful Android appium app testing on windows machine.

**Software:**

As of now they have released appium-server and appium-inspector as two seperate softwares. I'm using latest version of repositories.

- Appium server 1.22.0
- Appium Inspector 2021.9.2

**Appium Server Settings**

Make sure you have the same settings shown in the images below.

[image: appium simple tab]

[image: appium advanced settings]

[image: appium environment variables]

**Appium Inspector settings**

[image: appium inspector settings]

**Steps to start appium:**

- Start appium server first
- Then Start appium Inspector (make sure you add desired capabilities manually otherwise below error msg will arrive if you pasted Json representation manually)

> Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while
> processing the command. Original error: You must include a
> platformName capability.

After adding Representation it will look like below

```
{
  "platformName": "android",
  "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
  "appPackage": "com.coswarden",
  "appActivity": "ActivityHome"
}
```

Hope this will solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UI AutomatorViewer to find the element in the application.

Answer (score 0):

just install jdk8 because appium and uiautomator are compatible with java8 only problem will be solved. And follow below steps:

1. Right Click on the My Computer and Select the properties
2. Click on advanced system settings
3. Click on Environment Variables
4. Click on new Button of User variables
5. Type PATH in the Variable name.
6. Copy the path of bin folder which is installed in `JDK` folder.
7. Paste Path of bin folder in Variable value and click on OK Button.
8. You can follow a similar process to set `CLASSPATH`.
   and restart your PC
9. Go to command prompt and type `javac` command and check java8 is installed properly or not.
   And see whether android sdk has tools folder in it, In which uiautomator is present

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling to get started, I will add several screenshots to show the complete setup I have for Appium Server GUI, and Appium Inspector.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start the session freshly , it works.